# Append to a 2 dimensional array with mixed while reading a csv file in python

Tags: python, list, csv, multidimensional-array, append

I have a comma seperated csv file "Brent 3.csv":
Rows look like this:

```
2014.03.12 23:59:59,2014.03.20 23:59:59,BRENTSPOT,Brent 
1,1.29,1.6,0.8568833439015613,91.09,3.5,2.053,-0.035\n

2014.04.01 23:59:59,2014.04.02 23:59:59,BRENTSPOT,Brent 
1,1.39,1.4,0.8568833439015613,89.59999999999999,3.5,2.053,-0.036\n
```

Now what I wanted to do is to create a two dimensional mixed list with strings and float values.

```
import os

def create_list(stratname,directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    temp = []

    for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        if stratname in file:
            TDFile=open(file,"r")

            for i,line in enumerate(TDFile):
                s = line.split(',')
                for x in s:   
                    try:
                        temp.append(float(x))
                    except ValueError:
                        temp.append(x)
    return temp


brent3 = create_list("Brent 3",strategydir)

print(brent3)
```

I know that I should use

```
temp.append([float(x)])
```

but that does only create a list that looks like that:

```
['2014.03.12 23:59:59', '2014.03.20 23:59:59', 'BRENTSPOT', 'Brent 1', [1.29], [1.6], [0.8568833439015613], [91.09], [3.5], [2.053], [-0.035], '2014.04.01 23:59:59',    ...   ]
```

It should be:

```
[['2014.03.12 23:59:59', '2014.03.20 23:59:59', 'BRENTSPOT', 'Brent 1', 1.29, 1.6, 0.8568833439015613, 91.09, 3.5, 2.053, -0.035], ['2014.04.01 23:59:59', .....]]
```

I just can't seem to find the answer how to get each line of the csv file in [[first line],[second line]] format.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `pandas`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv = """2014.03.12 23:59:59,2014.03.20 23:59:59,BRENTSPOT,Brent 1,1.29,1.6,0.8568833439015613,91.09,3.5,2.053,-0.035\n
2014.04.01 23:59:59,2014.04.02 23:59:59,BRENTSPOT,Brent 1,1.39,1.4,0.8568833439015613,89.59999999999999,3.5,2.053,-0.036\n"""

print(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), header=None).values.tolist())
```

which yields

```
[['2014.03.12 23:59:59', '2014.03.20 23:59:59', 'BRENTSPOT', 'Brent 1', 1.29, 1.6, 0.8568833439015613, 91.09, 3.5, 2.053, -0.035],
 ['2014.04.01 23:59:59', '2014.04.02 23:59:59', 'BRENTSPOT', 'Brent 1', 1.39, 1.4, 0.8568833439015613, 89.59999999999998, 3.5, 2.053, -0.036000000000000004]]
```

If you want to use your file `Brent 3.csv` replace the call to `io.StringIO` with the path of the file.

Comment: By replacing csv with the directory of the file, now I get [[...\\Strategy Returns\\Brent 3.csv']] as a return. using pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), header=None).values.tolist()

Comment: Do not only replace `csv` but `io.StringIO(csv)` with your path as a string. `io.StringIO(csv)` makes `csv` be treated like a .csv file on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_list(stratname,directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    temp = []
    fin = []

    for file in glob.glob("*.csv"): # search file
        if stratname in file:
            TDFile=open(file,"r")

            for line in TDFile: # go throug every line in file
                temp = []
                s = line.split(',')
                for x in s:
                    try:
                        temp.append(round(float(x),3))
                    except ValueError:
                        temp.append(x)
                fin.append(temp)
    return fin
```

This solved the problem. I added another array fin = [], which I appended the temporary value to for each line and emptying the values from temp = [] again for the next line in the file.